# Plugin: Relative URL to images in another folder accessed inside a JS file

Tags: plugin-development

I have this Wordpress plugin file structure with "myfolder" as the main folder. There is another subfolder inside this main folder named as "resources". Inside this resources folder contains two subfolders: a) JS  b.) images

Inside images folder I have one image "myimage.png".
Inside JS file, I have a script named "myscript.js".

I would like to access the image "myimage.png" in images folder inside my javascript file "myscript.js".

I have tried the following but it does not work(does not resolve):

```
<img src="../images/myimage.png">
<img src="images/myimage.png">
<img src="resources/images/myimage.png">
<img src="../resources/images/myimage.png">
<img src="myfolder/resources/images/myimage.png">
<img src="../myfolder/resources/images/myimage.png">
```

Of course the absolute URL path works but I want this application to work with other sites so coding the absolute URL path is not a feasible solution.

I know that Wordpress also has this magic function:

```
$myicons= plugins_url('resources/images/myimage.png', __FILE__ );
```

But that will work only inside the PHP plugin file and I'm accessing the image inside a JS file. Any ideas how to make this work without rearranging the current file structure? Is there a JS function equivalent of "plugins_url" in Wordpress? Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For this purpose you can use [`wp_localize_cript()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) function, like this:

```
function localize_my_script() {
    $image_url = plugins_url( 'resources/images/myimage.png', __FILE__ );
    $localizations = array( 'imageURL' => $image_url );

    wp_localize_script( 'my-script-handle', 'localizedVars', $localizations );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'localize_my_script' );
```

That is assuming that you have properly enqueued your script with `my-script-handle` handle as an example.

Comment: HOLY CRAP! I have been searching for this solution for so long! Thank your for sharing

Comment: Thank you for this! put me on the right track